# How to get docblock from functions with mirrors

Tags: reflection, dart

I have a function and want to get its docblock with mirrors. Do mirrors already support that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean comments when you say "DocBlock" or something like javadoc-style comments like:

```
/**
 * Comment
 */

// Comment
```

Then this is not possible.

But you can create Annotations and use this as a doc:

```
@Doc("Some Documentation")
class SomeClass {

}

TypeMirror tm = reflectType(SomeClass );

print((tm.metadata.first.reflectee as Doc).string);
```

But I guess this is not what you are looking for?

There is a Comment class in dart:mirror - but note that it is not used and dart:mirror is officially "unstable".

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was what I was looking for. It's a pity that this isn't supported :(

Comment: I also looked at the dart analyzer. This gives you more information but not everything!